# Active data copying

Tags: c++

Is this expression correct?

```
{
    char a;
    char *temp;
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        strcpy(&temp[j], (char*)a);
    }
}
```

in this code `a` gets updated externally by the user input/key stroke. I want to copy all incoming/updated `a` to the `temp` as an entire string.

Comment: @ObscureRobot: You can do named links in comments with the [name](address) format.

Comment: that's a bug in StackOverflow's code that automatically turns short answers into comments. I thought I already deleted that comment, I've delete it once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since '`a`' in your example is not null-terminated and you want to assign a single character in string buffer, you can do:

```
 int const buffer_size = 5;
 char a = 'c';
 char *temp = new char[buffer_size]; // Remember to allocate your string buffer
 temp[index] = a;
 // .....

 delete[] temp; // free buffer.
```

`index` is an `int` which you can use to keep track of next position in buffer.

Answer (score 0):

No for a few reasons:

- `temp` isn't initialised, it's pointing to some random location and doesn't have any memory allocated for it, so you're just going to be writing over a random part of memory (and/or crash).
- `a` is a single `char` and you're treating it's value as a string (`char*`) using `strcpy` (I'm assuming you meant `(char*)&a` which is still wrong).
- `strcpy` continues copying `char`s from the source (`a`) to the destination until it hits a `'\0'` in the source...which could be anywhere since `a` is **not a NUL terminated string** but a `char`.

If you want to write/append a single `char` to a string/buffer you just do `buffer[position] = character`, where `buffer` is a `char[]` or a `char*` pointing to a block of *allocated memory*, `position` is the position in the buffer you want to stick the `char`, and `character` is obviously that `char`.

Anyway, I've got no idea what you're trying to do or the logic behind why you're trying to do whatever it is you're trying to do like this.

**EDIT:** And also you have this tagged as C++, why aren't you using `std::string` and `std::cin` if you are in fact using C++?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong in so many ways:

1. You cannot cast a char to a char*.
   You have to do something like this: `(char *)&a;` and since `a` is a char, you don't need to cast it at all.
2. You don't need to `strcpy` it. You can just do something like:
   `temp[j] = a;`
3. `char *temp` has not associated memory assigned to it. So you need to do something like this: `char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);`

Complete code here:

```
{
 char a = myFunToGetInput();
 char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * len));
 for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
   temp[j] = a;
 }
}
```

Or if you have used memset before:

```
{
 char a = myFunToGetInput();
 char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * len));
 memset(temp, (unsigned char)a, len);
}
```

Comment: That would be a good answer for C. In C++, use `std::string` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Been working with C a lot lately so its stuck in my mind. Thanks for the tip though.